# I have a problem with solving this integral by partial fraction

Tags: integration

I have an example like this :

$\int \frac{1}{x^{4}}dx$ = $\int x^{-4}dx$ = $\frac{1}{-4 + 1}x^{-4 + 1}+C$ = $\frac{1}{-3}x^{-3}+C$

What if this?

$\int \frac{1}{2x-10}dx$ = ?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle \int\! x^r \, dx=\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}+C$ for $\color{red}{r \ne -1}$.

Let $u = 2x-10$ then $dx = \frac{1}{2}du$ and

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{2x-10}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u}\,du =\frac{1}{2}\ln|u|+C = \frac{1}{2}\ln|2x-10|+C.   $

Comment: the correct result must be $$\frac{1}{2}\ln|2x-10|+C$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thanks - I forgot the absolute value!